# ag_e_parser_bad_property_value Silverlight Binding Page Title

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

XAML:

```
<navigation:Page ... Title="{Binding Name}">
```

C#

```
public TablePage()
{
    this.DataContext = new Table() 
    { 
        Name = "Finding Table"
    };
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Getting a ag_e_parser_bad_property_value error in InitializeComponent at the point where the title binding is happening. I've tried adding static text which works fine. If I use binding anywhere else eg:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

This doesn't work either.

I'm guessing it's complaining because the DataContext object isn't set but if I put in a break point before the InitializeComponent I can confirm it is populated and the Name property is set.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only use data binding on properties that are supported by `DependencyProperty`.  If you take a look at the docs for `TextBlock` for example you will find that the `Text` property has a matching `TextProperty` public static field of type `DependencyProperty`.

If you look at the docs for `Page` you will find that there is no `TitleProperty` defined, the `Title` property is therefore not a dependency property.

**Edit**

There is no way to "override" this however you could create an attached property:-

```
public static class Helper
{
    #region public attached string Title
    public static string GetTitle(Page element)
    {
        if (element == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
        }
        return element.GetValue(TitleProperty) as string;
    }

    public static void SetTitle(Page element, string value)
    {
        if (element == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
        }
        element.SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                    "Title",
                    typeof(string),
                    typeof(Helper),
                    new PropertyMetadata(null, OnTitlePropertyChanged));

    private static void OnTitlePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Page source = d as Page;
        source.Title = e.NewValue as string;
    }
    #endregion public attached string Title

}
```

Now your page xaml might look a bit like:-

```
<navigation:Page ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication1"
    local:Helper.Title="{Binding Name}">
```

Comment: ah I see. I assume there is no way to override this?

Comment: @zXynK: An attached property would probably work in your case, edit answer to show how that is done.

Comment: That really is silly that Title isn't a DependencyProperty. But this is a nice solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Ken: I agree it is a shocking oversight.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to MyPage.xaml.cs:

```
public new string Title
{
  get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
  set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Title",
      typeof(string),
      typeof(Page),
      new PropertyMetadata(""));
```

Once you add this property (dependency property) to your code behind, your code will work as normal.